# Combine xargs -I with sed

Tags: sed, cp, xargs

I want to use find to find certain files and then use xargs with cp and sed to move these files to another folder and rename them. I know how to do this in a loop, but that is not what I am looking for.

I tried:

```
find ${FOLDER} -iname "*${SOME_STRING}*" | xargs -I {} cp {} $(echo {} | sed 's/ABC/XYZ/g')
```

Why is this not working and what would be a solution?

Comment: How is it not working? What is it doing and what do you want it to do? Your command doesn't include `cp`, it will only print names. Is that what you want? Please [edit] your question and show us an example we can test and the result you are expecting.

Comment: How would the echo in that variable assignment know what `{}` means ? It just passes it literally to `sed` so nothing gets replaces hence the result of that assignment is `{}` and if you `set -x` before running that command you'll see the shell executes `xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' '{}'` which results in `cp: ‘./blah-blah’ and ‘./blah-blah’ are the same file` etc
The proper way would be smth like `find . -name whatever -exec sh -c 'cp "$0" "${0//ABC/XYZ}"' {} \;` which handles all kind of filenames.

Answer (score 5):

Try this.  It doesn't need `xargs`, just `find`, `sed` and `copy`. It won't change any files, but *will* print a list of shell commands to copy the files.  So if you like the commands it prints, then you run it again and remove the `#` before the `sh -x` on the last line and let the shell execute the commands.

```
find "${FOLDER:-.}" -iname "*${SOME_STRING:-ABC}*" |
sed "
    s/^/'/                      # surround filename with single quotes
    s/$/'/
    h                           # save filename in the sed hold space
    s/ABC/XYZ/g                 # change filename
    H                           # append to hold space (separates with newline)
    g                           # get original and modified from hold
    s/\n/ /g                    # replace the newline with a space
    s/^/cp -i/                  # make it into a copy command
"  #| sh -x                     # optionally pipe to shell
```

Why is this approach better than `xargs` in this case?  Because this method starts only 3 processes total (`find`, `sed`, and `sh`) in addition to the required `cp` command for each file.

To use `xargs`, processing each filename would require more processes than the single required `cp` command.

It's much more efficient to let the one invocation of sed generate *all* of the `cp` commands, than to invoke a new `sed` process for each filename.

Comment: Fails for files like: `My brother's 12" ABC-records worth >100$.txt`, and `touch Y-"$(perl -e 'print pack("c*",1..9,11..46,48..255)')"`

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
find ${FOLDER} -iname "*${SOME_STRING}*" |
  parallel cp {} '{= s/ABC/XYZ/g =}'
```

The {= =} construct contains a Perl expression that changes $_.

One of the advantages is that GNU Parallel does The Right Thing even if you have files called:

```
My brother's 12" records worth >100$.txt
```

or horrors like:

```
touch Y-"$(perl -e 'print pack("c*",1..9,11..46,48..255)')"
```